# Insert a '*' between each two characters in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, insert

I need to insert a `'*'` between each two characters in a string in Python, for example, for `'ABCDE'` I need to get `'A*B*C*D*E'`. What's a Python way of doing it?

Comment: `'*'.join('ABCDE')`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution

```
string ='ABCDE'
x = '*'
print(x.join(string))
```